# Python import in Init

Tags: python, import

I am writing a lot of tests at the moment that all use pytest. So the first time of every file is import pytest. Is there a way to import it somewhere else for example the `__init__.py`

```
tests
   - unit_tests
       - __init__.py
       - test_service.py
       - test_plan.py
       - test_api.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `import` statement has two purposes:

1. Define a module, if necessary
2. Add a name for that module in the current scope.

While putting `import pytest` in `__init__.py` would take care of the first one, it does nothing for the second. You have no way of *using* `pytest` in each module unless you import `sys` and use `sys.modules['pytest']` everywhere you would have used `pytest` alone. But that's ugly, so you might think, "Hey, I'll just write

```
pytest = sys.modules['pytest']
```

to make a global name `pytest` refer to the module."

But that's exactly what `import pytest` already does.